# How do I allow a user to select/highlight multiple children on a canvas?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, graphics

So I have a canvas that is filled with 110 objects that inherit from text block and each object has its own click event and mouse over event.  Clicking will allow the user to change properties behind the object by clicking a button.

Example:

The user clicks an object they want to change data for.  They will then click another button, which will correspond to a specific change in the data behind it... i.e. the user clicks object labeled "105" and changes its "binCode" property from 0 to a 1.

How can I allow the user to click/select/highlight multiple objects to allow them to change the data all at once.  There are many situations where a whole row of objects will need the exact same change in data.  It is inefficient to make the user do the same thing 10 times in a row when they should be able to highlight a whole row and click a button once.

Any help would be great, I really don't have any idea on how to go about doing this.

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to keep track of the clicked objects. This should be done with the click event. Either by changing a property of the object or by storing the reference to this specific object in a list.

When you press the change button you should loop over all clicked objects and make the change on them. Depending on how you keep track of the clicked objects you either loop over all object and check if it was clicked or not or you loop over the list of clicked objects.

Don't forget to "un-click" the objects once you have made the change.